# How to Install Euro Truck Simulator 2 in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, euro-truck-simulator-2

I'm using Ubuntu operating system. I wish to install Euro Truck Simulator 2 for Ubuntu. So I search for that, and I get the `.exe` file of the trial version from http://www.eurotrucksimulator2.com/download.php. But I don't know how to install it. Also I don't know, whether it is installation file or not.

Can anyone please help me,

1. Where did I get the Euro Truck Simulator 2 installation file?
2. How to Install it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you get your ETS 2 copy? Steam?

Comment: http://www.eurotrucksimulator2.com/download.php

Comment: Are you asking where the `.exe` file came from or where did it go to after you downloaded it from the website?

Comment: No, The file is downloaded as tar file, So I extract the file, once extract it show the file has .exe, So I don't know how to install from that .exe file

Comment: The `.exe` is the install file?

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't support Windows executables (.exe). Look for a .sh file or some readme.txt, which leads you through the installation process.

Comment: I disagree with the close for Off-Topic because unreleased or illegal. the Euro Truck Simulator 2 Linux Version is a product that is freely available on Steam: http://store.steampowered.com/app/227300/. The user simply downloaded the free Windows Trial, thinking it was a complete game.

Comment: @Nzall I agree it shouldn't be closed for that reason. I voted for unclear, though, since OP didn't post what the actual problem is. "Please guide me through a linux installation" is no valid question imho.

Comment: I installed the steam, and I try to install the euro truck simulator 2 demo. But it not supporting for me to downoad

Comment: how can I install?

Answer (score 8):

Linux versions are only distributed through [steam](http://steampowered.com), according to the Euro Truck 2 Simulator download page.

You'll need a Linux version of the Steam client.  Installing the game involves purchasing Euro Truck Simulator 2 from the Steam store, then let steam download the game to your computer.  Usually steam handles the setup steps when you first run the game.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you are saying. I'm new to this

Comment: How could I run it, I don't know how to setup it?

Comment: @Ganapathy You'll have to install steam for linux, then use that to sign into your steam account while in linux, and then select Euro Truck Simulator 2 from the list of games in your library.

Comment: @Ganapathy in addition to what Shadur said, you'll also have to add a license Euro Truck Simulator 2 to your Steam account. This probably means that you need to look up the email you got when you bought Euro Truck Simulator 2 for a license key and use the "add a steam game to steam" button in the Steam desktop client to add that key. If the key doesn't work, you'll have to contact the creators of the game and ask them if you could have a steam license key so you can install it on Linux.

Comment: Ok, downloading from steam is free or I need to purchase?

Comment: Can you pls tell, From where I can download a steam?

Comment: steampowered.com

Comment: https://itsfoss.com/install-steam-ubuntu-linux/

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier to get the game for Windows. You need Wine for it. After you install wine for your Ubuntu, click right button in setup.exe and install the game, mark all options for install - framenet, directX, etc.

If the game is for Ubuntu and is .deb file install with gdebi package.